# Pronunciación letras "d", "b" y "v" entre vocales

Tags: pronunciación

Mi lengua nativa es el español y recientemente me percaté que al momento de pronunciar la letra ***d***, como en el caso de

> cada, asado, soldado, jugada, nado

y la letra ***b*** (o *v* como fonema *b*) como en

> acabar, guayaba, navío, a veces, saber, revés

Estas letras cuando se encuentran en medio de dos sonidos vocálicos se pronuncian diferente, sin demasiada fuerza, no hay explosión de aire al pronunciarlas.

En el caso de la letra ***d***, a diferencia de cuando se halla al inicio de una palabra, sílaba después de consonante u oración en general como en

> mando, diario, senda, domo, mundo , dama

la lengua no toca el paladar y aún es entendible su pronunciación e igual ocurre con la letra ***b***, en palabras como

> barco, vida, bueno, venir, combo, envío

la pronunciacion tiene mayor fuerza, más sin embargo entre vocales, los labios se aproximan entre sí, mas no tienen contacto al momento de la pronunciación.

Escuchando audios y viendo videos de otros acentos (mi acento es el neutro colombiano que se habla en Bogotá), noto que es también evidente en otras regiones de la comunidad hispanohablante. Viendo esto mis dudas son:

¿Es común o general esta pronunciación? ¿Tiene algún nombre este fenómeno de pronunciación?
¿En qué casos no ocurre?

Comment: ¡Interesante pregunta! Bienvenido a [spanish.se], a ver si conseguimos desentrañar el tema. ¿Podrías por cierto añadir referencias a dichos audios para que podamos oír lo que comentas?

Comment: Nota: lo mismo ocurre con la *g*. Los fonemas [d], [b] y [g] son oclusivos, pero se vuelven fricativos y se pronuncian como [[ð](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fricativa_dental_sonora)], [[β](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fricativa_bilabial_sonora)] y [[ɣ](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fricativa_velar_sonora)] en todas las posiciones salvo después de una pausa o una consonante nasal (o lateral en caso de la *d*).

Comment: Hay variaciones regionales, educacionales y de estilo. "De oído" te puedo decir que los colombianos ocluyen un poco más que los chilenos, aunque eso puede deberse a que los actores colombianos pronuncian mejor que yo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Es la pronunciación normal del español. El proceso se llama "lenición" (= debilitación) y ocurre cuando /b, d, g/ se pronuncian entre vocales (y otros contextos); dejan de ser consonantes oclusivas para pasar a ser aproximantes/fricativas. Puedes mirarlo en cualquier manual de fonética española, incluso en *Wikipedia*.

Answer (score 2):

Este fenómeno se llama [*lenición*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenici%C3%B3n).

Los sonidos `/b/`, `/d/`, `/g/` y `/ɟʝ/`<sup>1</sup> se realizan como los aproximantes `[β̞]`, `[ð̞]`, `[ɣ̞]` y `[ʝ]` (de aquí en adelante representadas sin tachuelas) en todas las posiciones excepto:

- después de pausa
- después de consonante nasal
- después de consonante lateral (en los casos de `/d/` y `[ɟʝ]`)

en estos contextos, son oclusivas sonoras (o una africada en el caso de `[ɟʝ]`).

e.j.

| Letter | Word-initial | After nasal | After lateral | Intervocal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| g | **g**ato `[ˈga.to]` | man**g**o `[ˈmaŋ.go]` | al**g**a `[ˈal.ɣa]` | ha**g**o `[ˈa.ɣo]` |
| b | **b**ato `[ˈba.to]` | mam**b**o `[ˈmam.bo]` | al**b**a `['al.βa]` | ha**v**o `['a.βo]` |
| d | **d**ato `[ˈda.to]` | man**d**o `[ˈman.do]` | hal**d**a `[ˈal.da]` | ha**d**o `[ˈa.ðo]` |
| y | **y**ago `[ˈɟʝa.ɣo]` | man**y**o `[ˈman.ɟʝo]` | al **y**a `[al.ɟʝa]` | a**y**o `[ˈa.ʝo]` |

---

**Fuentes:**

<sup>• [https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonología_del_español#Sonidos_consonánticos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonolog%C3%ADa_del_espa%C3%B1ol#Sonidos_conson%C3%A1nticos)</sup>
 <sup>• [https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcripción_fonética_del_español_con_el_AFI#cite_note-b-2](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcripci%C3%B3n_fon%C3%A9tica_del_espa%C3%B1ol_con_el_AFI#cite_note-b-2)</sup>

---

**Notas:**

<sup>1. En algunos dialectos de Argentina y Uruguay (*Rioplatense*) y Colombia,

  `[ɟʝ]` ~ `/ʝ/`  se manifiestan como:

  `[dʒ]` ~ `[ɟʝ]`

  `[ʒ]`  ~ `[dʒ]` o

  `[ʃ]`  ~ `[ʒ]`</sup>

Comment: Sería major sin `markdown de código fuente`  con pronunciaciones en AFI, porque no se leen bien aquí: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D34XB.png