# Spanish pronunciation of the word no

Tags: pronunciación, vocales

In Duolingo sessions, I keep tripping up over some mysterious difference between "no" being pronounced as "NO!" `[no]` and "NOH!" `[nɔ]`. What's the difference between these?

Comment: Did you see "noh" written with an H in Duolingo? Or are you referring to something you're hearing? If it's something you're hearing, please [edit] to explain in more detail what you're hearing.

Comment: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/34666/how-is-the-letter-o-pronounced

Comment: All vowels in Spanish are always pronounced with the same phones.

Answer (score 1):

No existen diferencias entre "No" y "Noh", ya que en español la "h" no se pronuncia, salvo en raros localismos, que normalmente se encuentran en lugares rurales con la sensación de una muy leve "h" aspirada, que no parece ser el caso.

Quizás la cuestión pueda responder a las diferentes formas de interpretación, donde la "o" de "no", se alarga o modula según los contextos, produciendo con ello una sensación errónea en la pronunciación. - ¡No!, ¡Noo!, ¿Nooo? - .

> There are no differences between "No" and "Noh", since in Spanish the
> "h" is not pronounced, except in rare localisms, which are normally
> found in rural places with the feeling of a very slight aspirated "h",
> which is not seems to be the case.
>
> Perhaps the question can respond to the different forms of
> interpretation, where the "o" of "no" is lengthened or modulated
> according to the contexts, thereby producing an erroneous sensation in
> the pronunciation. - ¡No!, ¡Noo!, ¿Nooo? - .